# Is there a way to only process one task at a time per linked block in TPL Dataflow?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have two classes, serviceclient, and a service. The serviceclient will generate messages that will be processed by the service. ServiceClient messages should be processed in a strictly FIFO order, with the next message only available when the previous one was finished processing.

To address this issue I put an action block in each serviceclient that calls the service directly to process the client message which works fine I think but requires the additional dependency injection. I was wondering if there is a way to set it up so that the service can link directly to the serviceclient messageblock so that it can concurrently process messages from multiple serviceclient message blocks, but only one message at a time from any particular serviceclient?

some code with the desired functionality::

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new Service();

        //I would like messages from these clients to be processed concurrently by service, but only one at a time per client. 
        //So if Client A has two messages in queue(a1, a2) and B has 3(b1,b2,b3), it will immediately take a1&b1. If a1 finishes, it will then take a2. if b1 finishes it will take b2, same with b2 and b3. It would never process a1 concurrently with a2, or b1 concurrently with b2 or b3. 
        service.AddClient(new ServiceClient());
        service.AddClient(new ServiceClient());
    }

    interface IServiceMessage
    {
        string Message { get; }
    }

    class ServiceClient
    {
        public BufferBlock<IServiceMessage> clientServiceMsgs = new BufferBlock<IServiceMessage>();

        public ServiceClient() {
            //run task to populate bufferblock 
        }
    }

    class Service
    {
        ActionBlock<IServiceMessage> processServiceMsgsBlock;

        public Service() {
            processServiceMsgsBlock = new ActionBlock<IServiceMessage>(ProcessServiceMessage);
        }  

        public async Task ProcessServiceMessage(IServiceMessage msg) {
            //process stuff
            return;
        }

        public void AddClient(ServiceClient client)
        {
            client.clientServiceMsgs.LinkTo(processServiceMsgsBlock);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some sample code that illustrates what your trying to do would go a long way in helping us to help you.

Comment: let me know if that clarifies things

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need TPL DataFlow here? I will give you two options without, then finally one with TPL Dataflow like you ask.

Each option shares the below.

```
public class ServiceClient
{
    public async Task<IServiceMessage> GetAsync(string filter)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return new ServiceMessage() { Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public async Task ProcessAsync(IServiceMessage message)
    {
        // do something with it
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}

public interface IServiceMessage
{
    string Message { get; }
}

public class ServiceMessage : IServiceMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Option 1 - A service kicks off a task to read and write data. Simply couple the Service and ServiceClient together in a third service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var service = new Service();
        var serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
        var processor = new ProducerConsumerService(serviceClient, service);
        processor.Process("A", cts.Token);
        processor.Process("B", cts.Token);
        processor.Process("C", cts.Token);
        processor.Process("D", cts.Token);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to shutdown");
        Console.Read();

        cts.Cancel();
        processor.WaitForCompletion();
    }
}

public class ProducerConsumerService
{
    private List<Task> _processTasks;
    private ServiceClient _serviceClient;
    private Service _service;

    public ProducerConsumerService(ServiceClient serviceClient, Service service)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
        _service = service;

        _processTasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public void Process(string filter, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _processTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = _serviceClient.Get(filter);
                _service.Process(message);
            }
        }));
    }

    public void WaitForCompletion()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(_processTasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
}
```

Option 2 - Same as Option 1 but with two tasks and a BlockingCollection which provides a bounded buffer between the producer (ServiceClient) and the consumer (Service).

```
public class ProducerBufferConsumerService
{
    private List<Task> _producerTasks;
    private List<Task> _consumerTasks;
    private ServiceClient _serviceClient;
    private Service _service;

    public ProducerBufferConsumerService(ServiceClient serviceClient, Service service)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
        _service = service;

        _producerTasks = new List<Task>();
        _consumerTasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public void Process(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var buffer = new BlockingCollection<IServiceMessage>(1000);
        _producerTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = await _serviceClient.GetAsync();
                buffer.Add(message, token);
            }

            buffer.CompleteAdding();
        }));

        _consumerTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && !buffer.IsAddingCompleted)
            {
                var message = buffer.Take(token);
                await _service.ProcessAsync(message);
            }
        }));
    }

    public void WaitForCompletion()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(_producerTasks.ToArray(), 10000);
        Task.WaitAll(_consumerTasks.ToArray(), 10000);
    }
}
```

Option 3 - Parallelize processing while maintaining order of a given ServiceClient

Not exactly what you requested, but close. You can parallelize your incoming ServiceClient data streams while maintaining correct ordering. In this example all ServiceClients post to a single block, which then feeds into 9 partitioned actionblocks..

Provide each message of a given service client a Guid Id. Then use GetHashCode() to turn that into a number. Reduce that number to a range of 1-9. Create 9 ActionBlocks and use the lambda in the LinkTo method to limit the link to a single number in that range. That way we create 9 partitions which each process a sub-range of the data. You can safely process in a parallelised way with independent actions while maintaining FIFO of a given id.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var filters = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        var service = new Service();
        var serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
        var partitioningService = new PartitioningService(serviceClient, service);
        var processingTask = Task.Run(() => partitioningService.Process(filters, cts.Token));


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to shutdown");
        Console.ReadKey();

        cts.Cancel();
        processingTask.Wait(10000);
    }
}

public interface IServiceMessage
{
    string Message { get; }
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceMessage : IServiceMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set;  }
}

public class RoutedMessage
{
    public IServiceMessage Message { get; set; }
    public int PartitionId { get; set; }
}

public class PartitioningService
{
    private ServiceClient _serviceClient;
    private Service _service;

    public PartitioningService(ServiceClient serviceClient, Service service)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
        _service = service;
    }

    public void Process(List<string> filters, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
        Func<IServiceMessage, RoutedMessage> partitioner = x => new RoutedMessage
            { 
                Message = x,
                PartitionId = x.Id.GetHashCode() / 1000000000
        };

        var partitionerBlock = new TransformBlock<IServiceMessage, RoutedMessage>(partitioner);
        var actionBlock1 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock2 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock3 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock4 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock5 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock6 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock7 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock8 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));
        var actionBlock9 = new ActionBlock<RoutedMessage>(async (RoutedMessage msg) => await _service.ProcessAsync(msg));

        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == -4);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == -3);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == -2);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == -1);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == 0);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == 1);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == 2);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == 3);
        partitionerBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, linkOptions, msg => msg.PartitionId == 4);

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    Guid filterId = Guid.NewGuid();

                    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        var message = await _serviceClient.GetAsync(filter);
                        message.Id = filterId;
                        await partitionerBlock.SendAsync(message);
                    }
                }));
        }

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        partitionerBlock.Complete();
        actionBlock1.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock2.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock3.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock4.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock5.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock6.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock7.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock8.Completion.Wait();
        actionBlock9.Completion.Wait();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 10000);
    }
}
```